Solving DAE's -
I'm trying to find the structure of degenerate stars (white dwarfs, neutron stars) using the standard equations of stellar structure and Chandra's equation of state. This is a set of DAE's:
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/roberts/Published/StructureOfDegenerateStars.nb
This runs but the solutions don't work. The error messages have nothing interesting to say:
NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
How do I make any progress?

Have you been able to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances?

No boundary conditions are specified for NDSolve, and there are too many StartingInitialConditions.  In addition, StartingInitialConditions can be specified only at one value of r.

Also, I recommend removing the expressions for x[r] and pressure[r] from NDSolve.

Please put your equations in youf question is a format that is easy to copy.

Thanks for the suggestions. To clarify the physics that motivates these equations: pressure[massdensity] is the equation state and thus is required. mR is required for the equation of hydrostatic equilibrium (first eon), so I don' see how to solve the problem without it.

I changed the list of functions to be found but it still fails in the same manner. There have to be initial conditions on both pressure and pressure'  for physical reasons.

The primary problem as I see is that there is no systematic way to search initial condition-space.

There has to be  an initial condition on both  pressure'  for physical reasons. pressure[Rmin]and mR[Rmax] are the natural physical parameters to vary.

mass density[Rmin] is another initial condition that could be used to parameterize the solutions.

@DavidRoberts Actually DAE solver and shooting methos are not compatibly since Mathematica DAE solver designed for initial value problem only. Therefore, we need some handmade method to solve your problem.  Please add equations in Latex form as well or give us link to the paper where you got this model.
